# Missing operand before 'And' operator, but rendering page

Tags: c#, asp.net, operand

I have a page which is throwing Missing operand before 'And' operator error on this code:

```
string filtre = (Request["pn"] == "Tous" ? "pn=pn" : "pn='" + Request["pn"] + "'");
filtre += (Request["dep"] == "Tous" ? "" : " and erreur=" + Request["dep"]);
filtre += (Request["err"] == "Tous" ? "" : " and reference=" + Request["err"]);
filtre += (Request["comp"] == "Tous" ? "" : " and compagnie='" + Request["comp"] + "'");
filtre += (Request["prob"] == "on" ? " and not reference=58" : "");
StringBuilder tbltxt = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow ligne in Datatbl.Tables["ins"].Select(filtre, (Request["tridep"] == "on" ? "erreur" : "datecr")))
```

The foreach line is throowing this error.

Even with this error the page gets rendered correctly. It is just annoying to get this error by e-mail even thogh the user did not get an error page.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you

EDIT:

1- This code generates an Excel sheet

2- Not all computers that loads the page generates this error

3- The Excel we use is Excel 2010

4- It throws this error 3 times every time time the error is generated

Here is the complete error message:

Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Missing operand before 'And' operator. 
System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse() 
System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type) 
System.Data.Select..ctor(DataTable table, String filterExpression, String sort, DataViewRowState recordStates) 
System.Data.DataTable.Select(String filterExpression, String sort) 
inspectionrapport.fonctions.Page_Load() in c:\Projets\Intranet\Timesheets\Timesheets\Rapports\insptest\inspectionrapport.aspx.cs:line 45 
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.ArglessFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o) 
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Could you write out the string that is generated for one example run?

Comment: Just a tip, if you have not already: press `cntrl + alt + E` to open the Exceptions dialog, then check the checkbox for `thrown` under `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`.

Comment: Just a shot: on the first test (`Request["pn"] == "Tous"`), change `pn=pn` to `pn='pn'`

Comment: Your code is complicated by the nested "?" inside the string concatenation and the nested Select and "?" inside the foreach statement. You may find it easier to debug if you simplify the code by removing the nesting.

Comment: Can you add what `filtre` contains just before your foreach?

Comment: It does it on an empty string and on non-empty strings. Exemple: pn=pn and erreur=33 and compagnie='EMD'

Comment: @andre-calil's comment above seems a likely cause of the problem

Comment: @Olivier anything so far?

Comment: Nope... Still having this error

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and found that the error is coming when the expression had a value that does not qualify the sort expression. Eg: The table  contains only 2 values : 1 or 2 in the column A, but the code tries to filter the row based on value 3 or blank.

Try to print the values that you get, probably you will find the incorrect expression.